# Confusion on "Data-linked elements"

Tags: javascript, jsviews

I am reading up this page http://www.jsviews.com/#linked-elem-syntax and testing a bit.

1. I like to start with this ..

> Notice that the `<input data-link="name trigger=true"/>` tag
>   automatically has two-way data-binding.

Am I correct to say that if removing "trigger=true" will make the one-way binding? Or, Is it still two-way binding?

The only difference that I found for having "trigger=true" and not having "trigger=true" is that you will get the update on property-changed event if you have "trigger=true". otherwise, you will see get the update on lost-focus event.

2. I am also confused about having ":" before at the end.

> Notice the full syntax for the  has an additional ':' before
>   the '}' at the end. It corresponds to the two-way data binding.

Does it mean that having ":" at the end has the same effect as having "trigger=true"?

But i tried the code below and it doesn't work like the code that has "trigger=true".

```
<input data-link="{:name:}"/>
```

Comment: Hi, what wrong with having "JsViews:" in title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section **Optional two-way data-binding** of http://www.jsviews.com/#linked-elem-syntax explains that the ":" at the end determines whether you have two-way binding or not.

If you do have two-way binding then you can also set `trigger=true` to trigger a binding update after every character entry (after key down). Otherwise, by default, the update is on "blur" or "change" only.

Comment: What about one-way binding to textbox?

Comment: linkTo allows you to bind to a different data property.
<input data-link="from linkTo=to trigger=true"/>
In this example from may or may not exist. So you optionally bind from. 'to' is the property you are binding to. trigger=true is optional.
<input data-link="{:from}"/> is one-way from data to the textbox.
See http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/edit/generic and https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/blob/master/test/unit-tests/tests-jsviews.js#L10536